# Opening email attachment in iPad

Tags: objective-c, email, attachment

Hey, am writing an application to try out ideas and want to be able to open/save email attachments similar to what happens with good reader, does anyone know of a good tutorial that explains how to do this?

Thanks, William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned this from http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/06/14/ipad-sdk-3-2-document-support-1/

and if you want to add your own filetypes read [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented something like this with the help of a book called [Beginning iPad Development for iPhone Developers](http://books.google.com/books?id=mTGLGxnth0YC&lpg=PP1&dq=ipad%20development&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) Chapter 10 covers this topic in great detail ... better than anything I could find online.

One of the authors, Jack Nutting, was even nice enough to help me get something working after I emailed him.  Good stuff.

Comment: thanks for the reply, a colleague at work has this book so I shall check it out